# How many watts does a 3/4hp disposal need to run

Tags: plumbing

How many watts does it take to run a 3/4 hp garbage disposal

Comment: Incidentally, entering "3/4 hp watts" into Google gets you a very quick answer. Google is pretty great at interpreting conversion requests.

Comment: What purpose do you need this wattage number for? Load calcs? Generator sizing?

Comment: Note that the rated power of a motor is generally output power. Input power will be higher, depending on power factor, and input VA will be higher again.

Answer (score 2):

A simple conversion is 1 HP = 750 watts, so 3/4 HP is about 560W

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of conversions sites and also found this handy site with a table. There also should be a nameplate on the motor that gives watts or startng watts.

https://www.generatorjoe.net/html/electricmotor.html